# I can't place xml tags where i want

Tags: php, xml

I get the xml output of the method below.
But I need to add code in the xml output.

When I add it this way, it falls under the `<cac: TaxScheme>` tag.

https://prnt.sc/q3eg7l

```
<cac:TaxTotal>
    <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="USD">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
    <cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="USD">0.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="USD">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:Name>TAX</cbc:Name>
                <cbc:TaxTypeCode>0015</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
            <cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>301</cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>
            <cbc:TaxExemptionReason>description</cbc:TaxExemptionReason>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:TaxSubtotal>
</cac:TaxTotal>
```

the important thing is that it is on the `<cac: TaxScheme>` tag.

```
<cac:TaxTotal>
    <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="USD">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
    <cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="USD">0.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="USD">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>301</cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>
            <cbc:TaxExemptionReason>description</cbc:TaxExemptionReason>            
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:Name>TAX</cbc:Name>
                <cbc:TaxTypeCode>0015</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:TaxSubtotal>
</cac:TaxTotal>
```

that is, it should be just below the `<cac: TaxCategory>` tag.

**php code**

```
$invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category = new \Bulut\eFaturaUBL\TaxCategory();
$invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category->TaxExemptionReasonCode = "301";
$invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category->TaxExemptionReason = "description";    
$invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category_Schema = new \Bulut\eFaturaUBL\TaxScheme();
$invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category_Schema->Name = "TAX";
$invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category_Schema->TaxTypeCode = "0015";
$invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category->TaxScheme = $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category_Schema;
$invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal->TaxCategory = $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category;      
$invoice_TaxTotal->TaxSubtotal = $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal;
$invoice->TaxTotal = $invoice_TaxTotal;
```

Comment: is there anyone who can help? :)

Comment: How's it going? I'm facing a similar issue, it always fails at "[BR-CL-22]-Tax exemption reason code identifier scheme identifier MUST belong to the CEF VATEX code list" in the validator: https://www.itb.ec.europa.eu/invoice/upload